# Existing pre-trained NLP models to detect if a text input is a question

Tags: python, nlp, transfer-learning

I would like to quickly filter text data into question and non-questions. Using the presence of question mark in the text is too crude. Are there any existing models I can use to aid me with my task?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple threads on Stack Overflow talking about this. Couple of examples can be found below:

- [Determine if a sentence is an inquiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083060/determine-if-a-sentence-is-an-inquiry)
- [NLTK. Detecting whether a sentence is Interogative or Not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100615/nltk-detecting-whether-a-sentence-is-interogative-or-not)

You can also take a look at [Natty](https://github.com/SOBotics/Natty). It's a bot on Stack Overflow, which reviews answers to old questions. You can see how effective it is in terms of detecting questions (every bot needs training, and Natty has been trained for quite a while). However it is written in Java, it may give you some ideas. Like [detecting keywords](https://github.com/SOBotics/Natty/blob/master/src/main/java/in/bhargavrao/stackoverflow/natty/filters/StartsWithKeywordFilter.java) alongside checking for presence of [question mark](https://github.com/SOBotics/Natty/blob/master/src/main/java/in/bhargavrao/stackoverflow/natty/filters/ContainsQMFilter.java).